# use of not in xpath query

Tags: php, xpath

i am fetching specific data from a site for which i am using XPath but for this i have to exclude few variables for which i have to use NOT. but this NOT is not working in the code please explain what i have to do to make it work :

**heres the html code**

```
<tr><td colspan="2" valign="top" align="left"><span class="tl-document">
<left>some text here
</left>
</span></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" valign="top" align="left">
<span class="text-id">some text here,<sup>a</sup><sup>b</sup></span>
<span class="text-id">some text here,<sup>a</sup></span>
</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" valign="top" class="right">
<sup>a</sup>some text here<br>
</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" valign="top" class="right">
<sup>b</sup>some text here<br>
</td></tr>
<td colspan="2" valign="top">
<br><div>
<span class="tl-default">Objective</span>
<p>some text here,</p>
</div>
<div>
<span class="tl-default">Methods</span>
<p>some text here,</p>
</div>
<div>
</td>
<td colspan="2" valign="top">
<br><div>
<span class="tl-default">Objective</span>
<p>some text here,</p>
</div>
</td>
```

trying to fetch  only not td containing class and align and for this i am using this method for my xpath :

```
$getnew="http://www.example.com/;
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHtmlFile($getnew);
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );
$y = $xpath->query('//td[@colspan="2" and valign="top" and (not(@class and @align))]');
$ycnt = $y->length;
for ( $idf=6; $idf<$ycnt; $idf++) 
{ if($idf==6){
  echo "<p class='artbox'>".$y->item($idf)->nodeValue."</p>";}
}
```

i am new to this so please suggest your opinions

Comment: What's the expected outcome?

Comment: all the text containing in this""<td colspan="2" valign="top">"" only not in this ""<td colspan="2" valign="top" align="left">"" and in this ""<td colspan="2" valign="top" class="right">"" @jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your logic is that no elements have both `@class` *and* `@align`, so the `not()` will always yield `true`.

Instead you should exclude elements that have either attribute:

```
//td[@colspan="2" and @valign="top" and not(@class or @align)]
```

Alternatively, to match elements that only have those two attributes, you can add a `count()` condition:

```
//td[@colspan="2" and @valign="top" and count(@*)=2]
```

#### Update

```
$query = '//td[@colspan="2" and @valign="top" and not(@class or @align)]';
foreach ($xpath->query($query) as $node) {
    // do something with $node
}
```

Comment: no not working , but i want NOT  syntax it would be better can you make it using NOT ...??

Comment: @MunanshuMadaan I've tested the above and it yields three elements on your HTML (which I assume is the expected outcome, which you have not specified) ... that said, I have updated my answer to include an alternative.

Comment: yeah your logic is right but count is not working may be  my loop logic is not right somewhere can you check that out

Comment: my expected outcome is i just want all the text in this ""<td colspan="2" valign="top">"" only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66446/discussion-between-munanshu-madaan-and-jack).

Comment: the logic you gave must work and i am just a beginner  in programming can you give me the code working in yours

Comment: @MunanshuMadaan There's not much code to show, really; I've updated the answer with what I used.